# How to fix javaScriptEnabled ? It always return null

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the value of javaScriptEnabled from the HttpServletRequest header. But i am always getting it as null.

I have been trying different websites to know how to get the values from HttpServletRequest header.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
System.out.println("value:" + request.getHeader("javaScriptEnabled"));
```

Value should come as true, as javascript is enabled in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your approach is correct. Browsers won't send you special HTTP HEADERs to tell you if JavaScript is enabled (or not).

In order to detect this, you need a different approach. There are many, but one I like (because it's simple) is:

```
1. Set a COOKIE using META TAG in your HTML saying that JS_ENABLED = false
2. Use JavaScript to change that value tu TRUE.
3. If value is changed on your next request, then JavaScript is effectively enabled and allowed to change cookie values.
```

Other technique might be using a special *AJAX request* to infer this.

I am assuming you need *server side detection*.

Comment: yes i need it for server side. but first i would like to know that is there a variable called "javaScriptEnabled".